# Entering PhD with bad masters grades and no thesis

Tags: phd, thesis, grades

I am a foreign national who came to the US to pursue my Master and now working at a robotics startup company. I had pretty good grades and awards from my bachelor's degree. But, after coming to the US, because of not eating well and having financial issues, I could not concentrate well on my master's degree and ended up getting just passing grade which is 3.0 out of 4.0. I did not do any thesis in my master. I really thought that this was the end and I would not pursue a PhD or come near academics at all in my life.

Lately, after working at my company, I feel like learning and knowing more about it. I am doing some online courses and learning constantly. But, I would like to pursue a PhD in the near future. My problems are, I don’t really have good connections with anyone to write me recommendation letters and I didn’t do a thesis in my master and moreover, I had just passing GPA and no research papers with my name. I don’t know how to revive myself from this situation. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have important industry contacts (for refernce letter and connections)?

Comment: Why are you giving me the impression that if someone does not do a PhD, his life is ruined?. Please note, I am not saying that you won't be successful in pursuing a PhD.

Comment: Have you considered doing a second masters that includes a thesis? This solves two issues - lack of research proof and you can use your better grade (assuming it is better) to demonstrate that the poor grade was an aberration.